# How to rebuild form after AJAX call

Tags: forms, 8, ajax

I'm attempting to allow the user to dynamically choose a number of fields based on a dropdown box using an ajax call, but I can't seem to get the ajax call to rebuild the form afterwards.

```
<?php
class AJAXexample extends BlockBase {
    public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        if (empty($form_state->getValue('number'))) {
            $form_state->setValue('number', 3);
        } 
        $form['columnNum'] = [
            '#title'   => t('Number of Columns'),
            '#type'    => 'select',
            '#options' => [
                1         => '1',
                2         => '2',
                3         => '3',
                4         => '4',
            ],
            '#default_value' => $this->configuration['columnNum'],
            '#empty_option'  => t('-select-'),
            '#ajax'          => [
                'callback'      => [$this, 'columnCallback'],
            ],
        ];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state->getValue('number'); $i += 1) {
            $form['column'][$i] = [
                $i => [
                    '#type'       => 'details',
                    '#title'      => t('Column '.$numTitle),
                    '#open'       => FALSE,
                    'columnTitle' => [
                        '#type'      => 'textfield',
                        '#title'     => t('Column Title'),
                        '#value'     => $config[0]['columnTitle'],
                    ],  
                ],
            ];  
        return $form;
    }

    public function columnCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form_state->setValue('number', 10);
        $form_state->setRebuild(true);
        return $form;
    }
}
```

The number of textfields is based on the form_state variable 'number'. The callback columnCallback changes the form_state variable to 10, and is fired when the 'columnNum' form field is changed. However the form isn't rebuilt with the new number of fields even though $form_state->setRebuild(); is called. Is there a way to get the form to rebuild after an ajax call?

NOTE: I have already tried techniques such as replacing or appending the items of the form inside of the actual ajax call but when that happens none of the input into the replaced fields get passed to $form_state.

UPDATE:
After attempting 4k4's solution I receive an error

```
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer::renderResponse() must be of the type array, null given, called in /Library/WebServer/Documents/aaep/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormAjaxResponseBuilder.php on line 89 and defined in Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer->renderResponse() (line 45 of /Library/WebServer/Documents/aaep/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/MainContent/AjaxRenderer.php).
```

The belief is that the error occurs because $form['column'] is returning null despite being created as a container in the blockForm function. I've attempted calling the callback in other ways like

```
'#ajax' => [
    'callback' => '::columnCallback',
]
```

and

```
'#ajax' => [
    'callback' => [$this, '\Drupal\my_examples\Plugin\Block\AJAXexample::columnCallback'],
]
```

But I receive the same error. Curiously, when I change the callback to return the entire $form instead of just $form['column'] it repeats the form (a copy of the form appears below the current form) and still without the proper number of columns.

Comment: Might be a typo but double checking, are you aware that in columnCallback the first argument is a typo (no space between array and &$form)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem is to handle the value for the column number. On the first build get it from configuration, on a rebuild get it from the user input and put it in `$columnNum`.

The second is to decide, what part of the form changes in AJAX and put this in a div container with the id `columns-wrapper`.

```
class AJAXexample extends BlockBase {
    public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $columnNum = empty($form_state->getValue('columnNum')) ? $this->configuration['columnNum'] : $form_state->getValue('columnNum');
        $form['columnNum'] = [
            '#title'   => t('Number of Columns'),
            '#type'    => 'select',
            '#options' => [
                1         => '1',
                2         => '2',
                3         => '3',
                4         => '4',
            ],
            '#default_value' => $this->configuration['columnNum'],
            '#empty_option'  => t('-select-'),
            '#ajax'          => [
                'callback'      => [$this, 'columnCallback'],
                'wrapper'       => 'columns-wrapper', 
            ],
        ];
        $form['column'] = [
            '#type' => 'container',
            '#attributes' => ['id' => 'columns-wrapper'],
        ];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columnNum; $i += 1) {
            $form['column'][$i] = [
                $i => [
                    '#type'       => 'details',
                    '#title'      => t('Column '.$numTitle),
                    '#open'       => FALSE,
                    'columnTitle' => [
                        '#type'      => 'textfield',
                        '#title'     => t('Column Title'),
                        '#value'     => $config[0]['columnTitle'],
                    ],  
                ],
            ];  
        return $form;
    }
```

In the callback we only need to return the ajax wrapper.

```
public function columnCallback(array&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['column'];
}
```

Drupal rebuilds the form on every ajax request and puts it in the parameter `$form` of the callback. It would make no sense to try to rebuild it again.

Comment: I receive an error after the ajax request is called. 'HTTP Result Code: 200' StatusText: OK ResponseText:

Comment: The test things I performed a die(print_r($form_state->getValues())); and it did properly display the proper columnNum value. It just errors out otherwise.

Comment: I've put the changes in your code for demonstration. Can't help with debugging without error messages with line numbers.

Comment: Any tips on a good way to get a more detailed error message? All I get is an error with a blank responsetext after the call is made.

Comment: Did you remove the syntax error from @Kevin's comment? Are there php errors in the error log? There should be plenty when testing new code like this.

Comment: I did remove the syntax error. Looking at the error log I see Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\AjaxRenderer::renderResponse() must be of the type array, null given. I'm assuming that [$this, columnCallback] isn't sending along the form properly?

Comment: Traced the error, it means `return $form['column']` is null, because the return value gets unchecked in `renderResponse()`. Might still be a problem with the parameter list of the callback, because we put at least a container in that form key and this would prevent this error.

Comment: I attempted other methods to issue the callback but I still receive the same error. Also if I change it to 'return $form' it returns the entire form and places it below the current form. Check my updated question for more details.

Comment: I did to solve it and had the same result as @4k4 said. The `$form['column']` is empty. After debugging, I found that the routing is a little bit tricky because it is returning from a exception. I don't know much what it is working because the controller is a `Closure` which blocked me debug it further.

Comment: It maybe a bug in Drupal because it seems only happen on using Form Ajax in Model. I guess...

Comment: If it is a bug, is there any kind of workaround I can do?

Comment: How do you rebuild the form without losing the state of the details element? When I have a few of them open and closed, and then add an additional one, the form rebuilds and they are all closed again.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work in a blockform, but it does work on a regular form, so I'll go ahead and award the points since it's most likely a drupal bug.

Comment: Could you try with `return $form['settings']['column'];`? In a config form that appears to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're missing `wrapper` method in your `'#ajax'` (next to `callback`) which consist the HTML `id` attribute of the area where the content returned by the callback should be placed. See: [Ajax API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/ajax/8.3.x). Then you've to make sure such container `id` exist.

Code example (simplified):

```
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['wrapper'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => array('id' => 'data-wrapper'),
        );
    $form['wrapper']['columnNum'] = [
        '#title'   => t('Number of Columns'),
        '#type'    => 'select',
        '#options' => [1 => '1', 2 => '2'],
        '#default_value' => $this->configuration['columnNum'],
        '#ajax'          => [
            'callback'   => '::columnCallback',
            'wrapper'    => 'data-wrapper',
        ],
    ];
}
public function columnCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['wrapper'];
}
```

---

For complete code example, see: [How to Add more option for type radios use Ajax in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/212417/1908).