# How to Add more option for type radios use Ajax in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

Hi I build Add more for radios  when click button load ajax. This ajax only add more options for radios . But not working , how to build used ajax add more options for type radios form ? Thanks

This code example my demo:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class DemoForm extends FormBase{

    public function getFormId()
    {
        return 'DemoForm';
    }
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state,$param = array())
    {
        $form['wrapper_data'] = array(
            '#type' => 'container',
            '#attributes' => array('id' => 'wrapper_data'),
        );  
        $form['wrapper_data']['data_media'] = array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => 'List Media',
            '#options' => array('aaa','bbb','cccc'), 

        );
        $form['wrapper_data']['load_more_data'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => 'Load More',
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => '::AjaxLoadMore',
                'wrapper' => 'wrapper_data',
            ),
        );

        return $form;
    }

    public function AjaxLoadMore(array &$form,FormStateInterface $formState){

        $form['data_media']['#options'] += array('bbbb'); // Want Add more options for radios

        return $form['wrapper_data'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete code example:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * File: src/Form/MyExampleForm.php
 * Contains \Drupal\mymodule\Form\MyExampleForm.
 */
namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class MyExampleForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'example_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}.
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['wrapper'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => array('id' => 'data-wrapper'),
        );

    /* // or:
    $form['wrapper'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Example title'),
      '#tree' => FALSE,
      '#prefix' => "<div id='data-wrapper'>",
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
    */

    /* // or:
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="data-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    */

    $form['wrapper']['data_media'] = array(
        '#type' => 'radios',
        //'#title' => 'Title',
        '#options' => array('aaa','bbb','cccc'), 
        );
    $form['wrapper']['more_data'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#value' => 'Show more',
        // @see: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/ajax/8.3.x
        '#ajax' => array(
          // The callback to invoke to handle the server side of the Ajax event.
          'callback' => [$form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object'], 'ajaxLoadMore'],
          // or: //'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxLoadMore'],
          // or: //'callback' => '::ajaxLoadMore',
          // @see: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/
          //'method' => 'replace', // May be: 'replaceWith' (default), 'append', 'prepend', 'before', 'after', or 'html'.
          // The HTML 'id' attribute of the area where the content returned by the callback should be placed.
          'wrapper' => 'data-wrapper',
          ),
        );
    $form['wrapper']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Confirm'),
        );

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Ajax handler for loading more radio options.
   */
  public function ajaxLoadMore(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    // Add more options for radios.
    $trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    if ($trigger['#value'] == 'Show more') {
      $form['wrapper']['data_media']['#options'] += array_merge($form['wrapper']['data_media']['#options'], ['bbbb']);
    }
    return $form['wrapper'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $values = $form_state->getValues();
    $trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    if ($trigger['#type'] === 'submit') {
      if (is_null($values['data_media'])) {
        $form_state->setErrorByName('data_media', t('Please select the option!'));
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_set_message($this->t('Your form has been submitted.'));
  }

}
```

Comment: I think this code doesn't solve the issue "The callback function must not alter the form or any other state." Why this is important for #options: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/resolve-the-error-an-illegal-choice-has-been-detected

Answer (score 2):

Move the code to add more radios to form build:

```
  if ($form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#value'] == 'Load More') {
    $form['wrapper_data']['data_media']['#options'] += array('bbbb');
  }
```

You can use `getTriggeringElemement()` to identify the button by checking a property of the element, if you want this can be the ajax callback itself.

Comment: Hi I used `getTriggeringElemement` but not working for radios . Could you show detail about your solution ? Thanks

Comment: `getTriggeringElement()` is to check if the button was clicked. The code in my answer is the complete solution.

Comment: I replace `$form['wrapper_data']['data_media']['#options'] += array('bbbb')` to `$form['wrapper_data']['data_media']['#options'] = array_merge($form['wrapper_data']['data_media']['#options'],array('bbbb'))` this working . Thank for your answer !